# Are we slowing down too much?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

It's normal that many questions come in first two days of private beta, and then number of questions decrease. However, typical site leaves private beta after a week and with more questions that we do. Does it mean that we are slowing down so much that it lead to postponing start of Latin's public beta? Are we even in danger of closing?

**Anyway: ask more questions!**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In simple terms: no.

First off, private betas are actually three weeks long now.

Second off, the frequency here is still normal. It's very common that private betas slow down as they go, and the Community Team know that. There's no danger of closure right now.

Third off, remember to focus on **quality not quantity**. more questions does not a good private beta make; *good* questions does.

Comment: I didn't know of the three weeks policy; it used to be one week when I last participated in a private beta. Where did you find the number? My google-fu is to weak to find it.

Comment: @PavelV. They changed it during the beta of [hardwarerecs.se]. There's a post on MSE I wrote about my concerns over this, which is my source for most of this information.

Comment: [Found it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266270/202747) Their reasoning behind it makes sense, so I'm no longer concerned.

Comment: Incidentally, this site has already been slated for public launch. And the timing of these milestones will be made more readily apparent with some upcoming changes to the private beta process.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Where can we see such information? Is it available to us in some way?

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Yay! Is there any specific reason for that, or is it standard procedure (I'm not entirely up to date).

Comment: @Cerberus Reason for what? I don't know what you are referring to.

Comment: You said "site has has already been slated for public launch". Is that normal, or, if not, to what reasons do we owe the pleasure?

Comment: @Cerberus Most sites do get slated for public launch at some point... The private beta shutdown rate is pretty low.